# Bug in IE9 (set focus in input field via internetexplorer.application object)

Tags: com, focus, internet-explorer-9

I have some code that basically creates a *COM* `internetexplorer.application` object

I scan through the *DOM*, find a password field element and then do the following:

`element.focus()`

This line puts the cursor in that password field

This code works in all IE versions except for IE9. But if you click the *Compatibility View button* that is located directly to the right side of the address bar next to the Refresh button it works (because it switches to `IE7/IE8 mode`)

I searched the net many days for an explanation, believe now that this must be a bug (or an undocumented change).

What is your opinion about this? Is that difference documented somewhere?